# How to automaticly place field next to each other user CSS bootstrap v3.2.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have create a future in my application that will allow me to create dynamic field on a page. What I need to do here is to display the those field the same way every time.

I want to be able to display up to 2 field next to each other "if any"
I have attached a screenshot on what I need the final display to look like
[image]

from the image below the field "No Longer an Employee" is a label and to the right of it there is a value in this case "NULL." And to the far right of it there is another field called "Outside Sales Primary Contact" with a value of "NULL."

So I want to display the field into 2 column if there is enough fields other wise put one on the left and nothing on the right.

not I don't need help with how to generate the field. I need help with CSS and bootstrap on how to display the column next to each other.

Comment: Try something based on reading the docs and post a JsBin, Fiddle, or Bootply. This looks like it's table with two table-cells, if there's nothing then don't fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

I may need some more details to clarify your question but I made you a demo codepen of what I think you're looking for.

**DEMO** - http://codepen.io/BooststrapBay/pen/DGzIu

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 example-form">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>No longer an employee</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Support level</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Previous role</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Attitude</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Attitude detail</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 example-form">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Outside sales primary contact</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Training primary contact</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Primary enrollment contact</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Birth month</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Birth day</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what I need here is to group a label and input field and put them in the same row next to each other